# Delete element from an Array in React.js

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I'm developing a pomodoro Task App in React JS. I have an array which it called "task", I'm using "useState" hook. I have no problem with adding new "task". But when I try to delete an element from this array, my function do nothing.

```js
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
```

Add Element function

```js
function addTask(data) {
  if (tasks.length === 0) {
    setTasks((task) => [
      ...task,
      {
        name: data.name,
        description: data.description,
        selected: true,
        duration: data.duration,
        pomodoros: data.pomodoros,
      },
    ]);
    return;
  }
  setTasks((task) => [
    ...task,
    {
      name: data.name,
      description: data.description,
      selected: true,
      duration: data.duration,
      pomodoros: data.pomodoros,
    },
  ]);
  return;
}
```

Delete Element function

```js
function deleteTask(index) {
  let currentName = tasks[index].nombre;
  setTasks((current) => current.filter((task) => task.name !== currentName));
}
```

I pass an index to this function as an argument, then match the current name of the object of the array with the correct element name in my array.
I print "task" array but it looks like nothing change.

I'm expecting an answer explaining it

Comment: When you debug, does `currentName` match the value you expect?  Does the `current.filter()` operation produce the result you expect?  Why are you using a property called `nombre` in one operation, but a property called `name` in another?  How do you guarantee they'll have the same value?  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Note that "React" is not a programming language, it's a UI framework. You're trying to delete an element from an array _in JavaScript_, and then you want to signal that update the way you tell React about _every_ change to state data. (And importantly, those are two different things. Either you need help deleting array elements, or you need help updating state in React)

Comment: @David I made a mistake on my post, instead of `nombre` should be `name`. I mean on my code file both are `name`.  By the way, inside of `current.filter()`, the result it is what I expected, it returns me an array without the current "task" I deleted. But my UI do nothing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans probably I need help updating state in React. Those function are in a TaskHook file, and I'm using context hook in there. I have other file with my UI, where I show all "tasks" and each "task" are components in other file. So inside of  "task" component, I'm calling the `delete function`. If i check inside of `current.filter()` I get what I expect, but my UI do nothing.

Comment: @AlvaroFelipePupucheMorales: Then now would be a good time to provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  Because the code you're showing us clearly uses entirely different property names.  Please provide the code you're asking about, not text which mostly looks like the code you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example code, In your delete function on your first line, you call for a item that does not exist within the array.

To be specific:

```
let currentName= tasks[index].nombre
```

And looking at your set example, you are using:

```
name : data.name
```

when setting.

I also noticed your trying to filter against names. I recommend you creating some sort of unique identification number, if you ever have tasks that have the same names.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by David and Fady, the issue is most likely from `.nombre` as there is no such key which exists and hence your filter method returns the array as it is.

From the intention of functions, the code snippet look good to me.

However, you may refer to [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4beno8?file=src%2FApp.tsx) for your reference. I have tried to create a very generic react app which showcases the behaviour explained above.

Comment: I'm looking for something like your StackBlitz, but I still have the problem. I separate "Task" into another component. And the array are in another file inside of a "context"